# How to skip Not Null values in dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset
[image]
I'm extracting results from the machine learning model and storing the result in the column 'new_locations_names'. **I want to skip the storing if the column value is already filled!** I mean I want it to store only in the NULL values rows in 'new_locations_names'.
**I want to do what's inside the (try) only for nan values.**

I'm trying using the following code but it is not working:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    if row['new_locations_names'] is not None:
        continue
    try:
        print("INDEX AT ",index)
        result = extract_location_with_xlm_roberta(row['translated_title'])
        print(result)
        data.at[index, 'new_locations_names'] = {'new_locations_names':result['text_locations_names']}
    except:
        print("EXCEPT ",index)
```

Any thoughts, please?

Comment: Consider including data in text format and not in images

Comment: Also the best practice will be to create a new data that has its id with the corresponding new_location names and then update/merge/join etc

Comment: Can you please add some data that is programable? It is easier to troubleshoot your problems if there is data that we can take into our own IDEs to help troubleshoot for example: data = {'Column1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) df = pd.DataFrame(data) Doing something like that would help immensely

Comment: Why not store in a dict fist and then convert that to a dataframe. As this kind of at or loc operations are quite slow ? It mostly is fast if you already have all the data in the rows of different columns/files. i often first put info first in a list of dicts and then convert it, merge it on id and use the vector operations pandas is good for.And do thing like data.assign(newlocation=lambda x: x["existing loc"].fillna(x["new locations"])